# Merging Schemas swagger UI Micronaut

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, micronaut, micronaut-client

I am trying to merge the additional files schema in micronaut swagger UI. I think the file is not picked up during the build time, quite not sure how to set the correct path for the additional file.

Inside resource the additional file is present

[image]

In the application.yml configuration I have set the below configuration

```
micronaut:
  openapi:
    additional:
      files= src/main/resources/swagger/swaggerSecuritySchemes.yml
```

**swaggerSecuritySchemes.yml**

```
securitySchemes:
  Open Id Connect:
    type: oauth2
    flows:
      authorizationCode:
        authorizationUrl: https://falconidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/connect/authorize
        tokenUrl: https://falconidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/connect/token
        refreshUrl: ""
        scopes:
          openid: Open Id scope
          profile: Name scope
          email: Email scope
        usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant: true
```

In the build swagger yml file, those configuration are not present, I think the file is not picked during the build process, how do we set the path for additional files

From the micronaut documentation

```
micronaut.openapi.additional.files={project.home}/src/test/resources/swagger
```

what is `project.home` ?

I tried the below code in the build.gradle file, but it didn't merge anything from the other file

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile).all {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs << '-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=MATERIAL'
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs << '-Dmicronaut.openapi.additional.files=src/main/resources/swagger'
    options.compilerArgs += ['--enable-preview']
}
```

**Update 1**

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    Open Id Connect:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        authorizationCode:
          authorizationUrl: https://falconidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/connect/authorize
          tokenUrl: https://falconidentityserver.azurewebsites.net/connect/token
          refreshUrl: ""
          clientId: xxxxxxxxxx
          clientSecret: xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
          scopes:
            openid: Open Id scope
            profile: Name scope
            email: Email scope
          usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant: true
```

Including the above definition merged the configuration, however on final document the **clientId**, **clientSecret** and **usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant** are not merged, why?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states, in order:

> To configure the path for additional swagger files you need to set System property micronaut.openapi.additional.files

`micronaut.openapi.additional.files` should be added as a ***System property*** for your build, as, *OpenAPI* documentation is generated at build / compile time and not at runtime, hence adding this property to `application.yml` (runtime) configuration will have no effect.

### Gradle:

If you are using *gradle*, you can add this `micronaut.openapi.additional.files` property either:

- to command-line *System properties* when launching your build:

  ```
  $ ./gradlew build -Dmicronaut.openapi.additional.files=src/main/resources/swagger
  ```
- to your project *gradle.properties* thus avoiding to add the *System property* at each build:

  ```
  systemProp.micronaut.openapi.additional.files=src/main/resources/swagger
  ```

### Maven:

If you are using *maven*, you can add the `micronaut.openapi.additional.files` property either:

- to command-line *System properties* as well when launching your build:

  ```
  $ mvn clean compile -Dmicronaut.openapi.additional.files=src/main/resources/swagger
  ```
- to your project descriptor *pom.xml* as a project property thus avoiding to add the *System property* at each build:

  ```
  <properties>
      <micronaut.openapi.additional.files>src/main/resources/swagger</micronaut.openapi.additional.files>
  </properties>
  ```

#### Side Note

Note that in both build tools configuration the `micronaut.openapi.additional.files` property was pointing toward a directory path (*src/main/resources/swagger*) and not a file path as the documentation lacks mentioning that this property takes directories and not explicit files as its value.

As far as I know, the additional files does not support the `securitySchemes` declaration and will only merge `paths` documentation. But I may have missed some details and otherwise feel free to [fire up an issue](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-openapi/issues/new/choose) in the *micronaut-openapi* repository.

Comment: Thanks for the info I tired the options.forkOptions.jvmArgs << '-Dmicronaut.openapi.additional.files=src/main/resources/swagger' in the build.gradle but nothing happens

Comment: Here is the repository https://github.com/anandjaisy/micronuatswaggermerging

Comment: Hey @SanJaisy, would you please update your thread to mention the EDIT post answer to allow for incremental information update.
Would you add you compilation output as well please?

Comment: Have you taken my note on * securitySchemes* as well? As far as I can tell, the answer should be acceptable since the issue is with you yaml file content.

Comment: Well, I was referring to https://editor.swagger.io/. I need to merge the security schema, can you please guide me on how can I do that.

Comment: maybe not the author's case but a warning to others - using a ".yaml" file instead of ".yml" will not work (not sure if this is a bug or some undocumented feature)

Comment: @tmarwen can you please check my Update 1 text, the document is merged now, but some fields are not merged any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me try this:

step 1: Create a folder with name `openapi` in the root directory.

step 2: Then manually create your yml in the openapi folder it self and mention your `schemas` in file as per the `(OpenAPI specification)`.

step 3: Now to merge both the files with the `generated OpenAPI definition`. You need to point Micronaut to look for additional `OpenAPI` yaml files in the openapi folder. So, you need to set the property micronaut.openapi.additional.files

To point micronaut to the openapi folder:

step 1: Look for the `openapi.properties` file in the root directory. If the file is not present create one.

step 2: Once we have the file paste this inside the file -> `micronaut.openapi.additional.files=openapi`

Confirmation: To confirm that the micronaut is actually merging the file or not after this process. Pay attention to the logs while server is getting started...

If the process is a success, you should be able to see these:-

```
Note: Merging Swagger OpenAPI YAML files from location: whateverDirectory/openapi
Note: Reading Swagger OpenAPI YAML file YourFileName.yml
```